# Extracting data using rex in splunk adds slash to the data

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a log that looks like this:

```
msg: time=2017-10-25.15:53:07:827 | msg2=somedata:sometitle[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
```

I want to get the value2 and here is my splunk query:

```
index="some_index" | rex "key2\s*(?<data2>.+)\s*"
```

here is the extracted `data2: \',\'value2\'\'`

I couldn't figure out how to exclude the slashes and just get value2. Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adjust your regex string to skip the quotes.

Try `... | rex field=msg2 "key2\":\"(?<data2>[^\"]+)" | ...`

Comment: RichG, a big THANK you.